# Dark Mode not working in 20.04

Tags: themes, 20.04, bug-reporting

I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and tried to enable dark mode but this is not working.

[image: ubuntu dark mode enabled]

[image: Dark mode not working]

Here is one more weird thing I noted. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 but this message shows 18.04.
[image: ubuntu 18.04 error on 20.04]

Update: This command solved the problem.
sudo apt-get install yaru-theme-gtk

Comment: Could you, please, check the Ubuntu version by typing:  `cat /etc/issue`, and post the output.

Comment: Here is the output Ubuntu 20.04 LTS \n \l

Comment: Then you are running on Ubuntu 20.04, I have no idea why the error message says that.

Comment: Is there a yaru-dark option?

Comment: Yes, there is yaru-dark option in tweaks shell theme only but it is also not working in files.

Comment: I have no idea why this isn't working.  Repeat the commands I gave you, then press `Alt + F2`, type 'r' in the box, and hit Enter.

Comment: Done. sudo apt-get install yaru-theme-gtk have done the task. Thanks :).

Comment: In my own case (Ubuntu 20.04), I had to first disable Night Light mode (in Displays). It conflicted with High-Contrast mode.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As listed in comments from the question, I did install Yaru:

```
sudo apt-get install yaru-theme-gtk
```

Then I selected the dark theme from Settings > Appearance and it worked.

I obtained a similar yet different result by installing gnome-tweak-tool and selecting the "Ambiance" theme.

Cheers!

Comment: works like a charm.

Comment: After this it takes a long time to open files window. I am using Ubuntu 20 LTS

Comment: It works but now icon and directory invisible because there color is also black is there any solution to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the Gnome-Tweak tool.  First, update, then add the Universe repository, and then install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open Gnome-Tweaks from Show Applications (or Activities), and click on Appearance.  Under Themes, dropdown Applications, and choose Adwaita-dark, or, as the case may be, Yaru-dark.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is no option for Adwaita-dark.

Comment: @Digvijaysingh Appearance --> Applications --> Adwaita-dark

Comment: This works but answer by JLoDoesIT is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 22.04.  I found that the 'Accessibility' 'High Contrast' was turned on in 'Settings'.  Turning this off let the Terminal window go to 'Dark' theme.

Hope this helps,
TD