# ubuntu 23.10 dark mode is not working

Tags: themes, release-management, appearance, 23.10, darktable

I installed ubuntu 23.10 yesterday. There is a bug here. Dark mode is not working. How can ı fix this bug?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi0Mj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dark Mode not working in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238385/dark-mode-not-working-in-20-04)

Answer (score 1):

Switch to Ubuntu Wyland mode

1. sudo apt-get install wayland-protocols
2. Log out
3. In Login screen switch to Wayland

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue after the upgrade to 23.10. However, when I log out I do not see a Wayland option. I only have `i3` and `i3 (debug)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 23.10: `gnome-control-center` stopped respecting the theme setting. I fixed it by installing `lxappearance`, picking the `Adwaita-dark` theme, and relogin.

Credit to [/u/sonsuz-bina](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/yg3uwv/comment/iu86oa0/)